# three20 TTTableSubtitleItem memory leak?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, three20

I create a TTTableSubtitleItem add it to an array, set the table datasource to the array and then release the array however leaks is showing a leak on TTTableSubtitleItem I am not sure why?

```
NSMutableArray *ar =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (item = (NSDictionary*)[enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tt://VideoListViewController/%@",
                        [item objectForKey:@"id"]];

    [ar addObject:[TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:[item objectForKey:@"name"]
                                           subtitle:[item objectForKey:@"description"]
                                                URL:result]];   

}
self.dataSource = [[myDataSource alloc] initWithItems:ar];
[ar release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your leak is at:

```
self.dataSource = [[myDataSource alloc] initWithItems:ar];
```

Change it to:

```
self.dataSource = [[[myDataSource alloc] initWithItems:ar] autorelease];
```

You allocated myDataSource and did not release it. Also, could you show me your 'dataSource' declaration in your .h file?

Comment: Hi Nayefc, as you have rightly pointed out that was the exact problem. Thanks for taking a look and helping me with this. I do not have a dataSource declaration in my header file do I need to put it in? I am using TTTableViewController so in code where i say self.datasource that is the first reference to it.

Comment: Oh okay. No you do not need to put it. I just thought you had it in your .h file since you used "self". I just asked you for it to make sure you released it incase you used "retain" in @property. But don't worry about it - you're good to go.